# Animating Charts in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, animation, charts, javafx

I have a JavaFX AreaChart, defined in my FXML file

```
<AreaChart id="myAreaChart"
         onMouseClicked="#handleAreaChartMouseClicked"
         GridPane.columnIndex="0"
         GridPane.rowIndex="0"
         fx:id="myAreaChart" >

  <xAxis>
      <NumberAxis>
      </NumberAxis>
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis></NumberAxis>
  </yAxis>
 </AreaChart>
```

It's styled with css, which I load from css\myAreaChartStyle.css in the start method

```
...
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    Scene cur  = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
       cur.getStylesheets().addAll(Main.class.getResource
   ("css\\myAreaChartStyle.css").toExternalForm());
...
```

Style works, and I have 3 areas in my chart, whose style is

```
.default-color0.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: #0000ff; } 
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: #0000ff; }
.default-color0.chart-series-area-line { -fx-fill: #0000ff; }


.default-color1.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: #0000ff; }
.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: #0000ff; }
.default-color1.chart-series-area-line { -fx-fill: #0000ff; }

.default-color2.chart-area-symbol { -fx-background-color: #0000ff; }
.default-color2.chart-series-area-fill { -fx-fill: #0000ff; }  
.default-color2.chart-series-area-line { -fx-fill: #0000ff; }
```

And here goes my question. I want to enable animation in my chart, I mean, I want color of my areas change smoothly from blue to white, for example, and it will be a kind of animation transition. I've tried to change css from my Controller class, but it doesn't work the way I want. So, how can I animate my chart?

Answer (score 0):

Check the charts examples provided under Ensenble.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html